# Passing parent object reference in Lambdas

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I'm trying to understand how the following lambda executes.

```
MyObject.LoginCompleted += (result) => DoSomething(result, MyObject);
```

I'm curious about the use of `MyObject` as a function parameter. Is this technically correct and will actually pass the reference of `MyObject` to `DoSomething()` when the event occurs? If so, how does a lambda expression store this reference inside itself when the above statement is executed? I'm curious because I can't think of an equivalent non-lambda statement for this. Say:

```
MyObject.LoginCompleted += DoSomething;
```

Now unless `LoginCompleted` event itself has a parameter for the parent object (e.g. `LoginCompleted(object sender...)` kind of stuff), we'll normally not be able to find about MyObject inside `DoSomething()`. This doesn't happen in the case of lambda, where we can send `MyObject` as a parameter to `DoSomething()` even when the event itself doesn't carry that information.

So my quesitons are:

1. Is my assumption about normal event handlers (through method-delegate) correct, or is there an equivalent code available which I'm missing?
2. Explanation of how lambda is storing the object reference internally?

Comment: Yes, the same MyObject will passed to the delegate. It named Closure - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming). Basically it will create anonymous class with property for MyObject, and method. And then it will create this anonymous class, set MyObject, and subscribe to that event.

Comment: You can use reflector to see how compiler converts your code to some other anonymous class etc.

Comment: If `LoginCompleted` wants a delegate with two parameters, then your lambda is invalid. If it doesn't then the `DoSomething` method group is invalid. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: Thanks. That's some help. 
@Jodrell: The event has only one parameter and is actually received by the lambda, which in turn calls `DoSomething`. There's nothing wrong with the syntax of this code. It is actually compiling.